# Leaves of mango tree are looking weird

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, leaves

So I've been growing this mango tree from a seed, and I'm amazed at how fast it's growing! However some of the leaves are looking a little weird. Some of them only have actual 'leaf' on one side of the stem.

Is this normal? It's also normal that they start off brown/red at first, right?

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]
[image: pic 3]

Thank you!

PS: if you have any tips to take care of this plant, be sure to share them :)